# Count strings in string array c++?

Tags: c++, string, count

How to sum number of strings in string array in which is not explicit defined how many elements it takes?

```
string str[] = { "astring", "bstring", "cstring", "dstring", "zstring" };
```

Need to find out how many elements array have?

Answer (score 10):

```
template< typename T, size_t N >
/*constexpr*/ size_t size( T(&arr)[N]) )
{
   return N;
}
```

`constexpr` if available (C++11) will allow you to use the return value for static (compile time) usage as a size of another array.

Comment: Better yet, make it `constexpr`

Comment: T will resolve to const if necessary. This will work on const input as well as non-const.

Comment: @CashCow But that won't ever make `size(x)` a constant expression. This means that `int other_array[size(some_array)];` will not be valid. If you make it `constexpr`, it is a constant expression.

Comment: you mean it should return constexpr size_t.

That works only in C++11

Comment: No, it should be `constexpr size_t size( T(&arr)[N]) )`.

Comment: I edited that in, but obviously it is not available yet on many compilers, including VS2010.

Comment: I think you can now safely edit `constexpr` in -- C++11 is widely supported these days.

Answer (score 8):

If `str[]` is statically defined (as shown), then this will work:

```
const size_t numElements = sizeof(str) / sizeof(str[0]);
```

If it's dynamically created, then you are going to need a *marker* to signal the last element (`0` is being typically used if it's an array of pointers).  Either that or the caller tells you how many elements there are (also common).

Comment: I don't get it.. what if length of str[0] differs from str[1]?

Comment: @LewsTherin: The OP apparently wants to know `how many elements array have`; the length of the elements doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the methods already listed in other answers, another way to do this might be to add a guard value to the end of the array, such as an empty string. You can then iterate through the array until you hit the guard value.

Personally, I'd probably use C++11 and

```
std::vector<std::string> la = { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
```

so you can just query `la.size()` to get what you wanted... at runtime, anyway. Unfortunately, i don't see a way to use this trick with `std::array`, so it isn't a perfect alternative.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Yes, but you can't initialise a `std::array` without supplying the array length in its type definition. And I don't think the OP wanted to solve the _"how many elements in my array"_ problem using _"well, first determine the number of elements in your array"_ ;-)

Answer (score 1):

one way using pointers to count the elements of the array:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str[] = { "astring", "bstring", "cstring", "dstring", "zstring" };
    cout << ((&str)[1] - str);  // 5
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:
5

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a separate variable for tracking array size.

```
String str[] = { "astring", "bstring", "cstring", "dstring", "zstring" };
int strNum = 5;
```

And then if I need to reference any of the strings, I can just call it as such:

```
String foo = str[strNum-1];
```

And any time I update the array in a loop, i simply use strNum as the index to start writing new strings to, and then place a strNum++ within the loop immediately after each new string.

Comment: This has the weakness that the two are independent.  Eventually someone will change one variable without changing the other and they will be out of sync.